# Style breaks when using TouchableOpacity instead of TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

[Here's how this part looks using TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ5vw.jpg)

[And here is the same thing, except with TouchableOpacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKKHa.jpg)

The code for this part:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <View style={styles.buyCoinsItem}>
        <View style={styles.cost}>
            <Text>{no_of_coins}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{product.priceString}</Text>
        <View style={{height:30, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop:10}}>
            {displayDiscount && 
            <View style={styles.discountContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.whiteText}>Save {discount}</Text>
            </View>
            }
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 10):

This is an annoying side effect of how the two components are implemented.

Essentially, `TouchableOpacity` is a native-backed View that supports touch interactions by calling `setNativeProps({ opacity })` on that view, whereas `TouchableWithoutFeedback` is simply wraps a native view and attaches the touch handlers.

In order to make `TouchableWithoutFeedback` behave like `TouchableOpacity`, nest an additional `View` inside it, and define any styles on the child view:

Before:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={...} style={styles.touchable}>
  // Touchable content
</TouchableOpacity>
```

After:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={...}>
  <View style={styles.touchable}>
    // Touchable content
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I'm not sure why the API was designed this way - my guess would be to avoid creating an additional native backing view for performance reasons when it's not needed.

However, from refactoring purposes, this makes it slightly more painful to move between different types of Touchables. In my projects, I typically create a custom Touchable component that wraps this logic behind a prop, or use something like [react-native-platform-touchable](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-platform-touchable), which gives you Android Material-style effects on Android.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, but what if I want my `TouchableOpacity` behave like `TouchableWithoutFeedback`?

Answer (score 2):

Nvm, I figured it out. I basically switched the `TouchableOpacity` with the outer `View`. So, like this:

```
<View style={styles.buyCoinsItem}>
    <TouchableOpacity>      
        <View style={styles.cost}>
            <Text>{no_of_coins}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{product.priceString}</Text>
        <View style={{height:30, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop:10}}>
            {displayDiscount && 
            <View style={styles.discountContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.whiteText}>Save {discount}</Text>
            </View>
            }
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```